# Reporting Services running on SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-express

I know I can run Reporting Services on SQL Server Express w/ Advanced Services.  The articles I have read do not touch on my question.  I'm wondering, in this scenario, can remote users execute reports from the report server remotely using URL access ex:)http://mySQLExpressBox/ReportServer/rptMyReport....... etc    - Or will reports only be served if the request comes from the same box/server?

Comment: My memory may be faulty on this, but for SQL Server **2005** you cannot remotely execute reports with Express Edition--only local requests will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible -- it works the same way non-express editions work. Were you running into any specific issues when you attempted to do this?

The restriction that ewall was referring to is not a restriction on remotely executed reports, but on remote data sources. The Express edition is limited to local data sources (although you can get around this with Linked Servers). Ex: ClientA can remotely execute http://mySQLExpressBox/ReportServer/rptMyReport but mySQLExpressBox can only retrieve the data for the report from itself.